# Django session id security tips?

Tags: python, django, cookies

I'm currently developing a site with Python + Django and making the login I started using the request.session[""] variables for the session the user was currently in, and i recently realized that when i do that it generates a cookie with the "sessionid" in it with a value every time the user logs in, something like this "c1cab412bc71e4xxxx1743344b3edbcc" and if I take that string and paste it in the cookie on other computer in other network and everything, i can have acces to the session without login in.

So what i'm asking here actually is if anyone can give me any tips of how can i add some security on my system or if i'm doing something wrong setting session variables?

Can anyone give me any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you say why exactly you think this is a security risk? The only way an attacker can get the cookie is with physical access to the machine, in which case they might as well use the already logged-in browser session.

Comment: that i can get acces to the session by only having this string "c1cab412bc71e4xxxx1743344b3edbcc" and nothing else and i don't know if this string can be generated by someoneone or what this string actually contains, if can be reversed or something

Comment: I found a couple of good tips here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure/8970#8970

Comment: What are the scenarios you imagine, that this might compromise the user's security?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no best way you can prevent this from what I know but you can send the owner of an account an email and set some type of 2fa.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that can do to help improve the security on session cookies.

- You can force a session to expire as soon as the user closes their browser.

In your `settings.py` file add:

```py
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True
```

- You can manually set the number of seconds until a session expires

Using the first argument(`request`) of any view:

```py
request.session.set_expiry(value) # number of seconds or timedelta object
```

To address your specific issue, please consider that what you are describing is actually one of the primary features of session security cookies.  They are convenience tools that enable users to use the secured parts of site without having to re-authenticate with every page request. Even the cross browser aspect of it is a feature since many apps and browsers provide a sync feature that allows you to share cookies and sessions datas with your mobile and other devices and other web browsers.

If you still feel that this is too significant of a security risk, then probably the safest approach would be to remove the `SessionMiddleware`
from `MIDDLEWARE` and `django.contrib.sessions` both in your `settings.py`